# Vim :o not working

Tags: vim

I might be mistaken but I think my command :o in vim is broken. When I try to open the .vimrc file, it opens a new file instead of my file, but if I use :tabnew, it works fine.

The commands I'm running are:

```
:o ~/.vimrc   --- This results in a new file window
:tabnew ~/.vimrc   --- opens the file correctly in a new tab
```

It only happens when I use "~/", If i'm in the same directory of the file and make a ":o .vimrc", it works.

Any clues?

I'm using version 8.0.344 (installed using homebrew) in macOS 10.12.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:o` does not open the file, you need `:e` (`:edit`). See `:help :o` and `:help :e` for more details.